# Не работает preg_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть следующий скрипт:

```
$output = file_get_contents('http://ru.heroquizz.com/t/zpa254ylg4');
echo preg_replace('/^yii2.co75701.tmweb.ru$/', "ru.heroquizz.com", $output);
```

Должна происходить замена ссылки, но она не происходит. Почему?

Answer (score 1):

точка - в регулярном выражении это любой символ. правильно:

```
echo preg_replace('/yii2\.co75701\.tmweb\.ru/', "ru.heroquizz.com", $output);
```

хотя на странице http://ru.heroquizz.com/t/zpa254ylg4 я yii2.co75701.tmweb.ru не нашел...

возможно вам нужно наоборот:

```
echo preg_replace('/ru\.heroquizz\.com/', "yii2.co75701.tmweb.ru", $output);
```

Comment: А я на своей странице использую. и все равно - не заменяется...

Comment: @TimurMusharapov только что сделал $output = file_get_contents('http://ru.heroquizz.com/t/zpa254ylg4');
echo preg_replace('/ru\.heroquizz\.com/', "yii2.co75701.tmweb.ru", $output); всё работает.... т.е. все ru.heroquizz.com заменились на yii2.co75701.tmweb.ru